# How to get a list of all objects present on the matplotlib axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I get a list of all objects (ploted data, vertical lines, horizontal lines, points, etc.) that are present on matplotlib axes? If there's no easy way of getting all of them inside a single list then how can I get this kind of list containing only vertical lines?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71961689/get-all-artists-of-an-axes-matplotlib/71966295#71966295

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all artists (plotted objects) with `ax.get_children().`
If you only care about lines, you can use `ax.get_lines()`. This [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71961689/get-all-artists-of-an-axes-matplotlib/71966295#71966295) has more details.

To select vertical lines only you can just just check their `x` coordinates.

```
vertical_lines = [l for l in ax.get_lines() if l.get_xdata()[0] == l.get_xdata()[1]]
```